# Visual studio closes when debugging (after install update 2)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I just installed the visual studio update 2 on two computers and now when I try to debug my program, the visual studio closes!!

It doesn't show any exception, just closes.
What should I do? I tried to reinstall the visual studio and install again but I got the same problem.

Comment: _"but I got the same error"_  - what error is that?

Comment: @Blachshma I mean Visual studio keeps closing when I debug.

Comment: Same problem here, it's quite annoying. Compiling works, running seems to work too, but once it starts the debugger it closes.

Comment: Ctrl+F5 (start without debugging) does work as a quick workaround.

Comment: if it closes abruptly check the the event logs for any errors and share them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Marc Paine (Visual Studio Debugger QA Lead):

> You are using the Visual Web Devleoper version of VS, correct? If so, we have a known bug in this CTP only affecting VWD. You can copy symsvr.dll from any other install of VS (other express versions or pro) into the common7\ide directory for VWD. That should fix the problem. We have fixed this problem already and it should be avialable in the next CTP.

Unfortunately it doesn't worked for me... so I tell it in the support forum but Microsoft just marked my feedback as closed and didn't answer me anymore...

So unfortunately my solution was formatting my computer.

Comment: Your follow-up comment to the Connect bug was posted yesterday.  It may take a few days (or longer) to get a response--the Visual Studio team is a very busy group of people.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis I understand. But they marked my question as closed. If anybody was still analyzing my issue then why mark as closed?

Comment: Its state was changed to Closed before your latest comment made it into our internal bug system.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis No, I made a comment in 02/07/2013 and the thread was closed  02/08/2013.

Comment: There is a delay between the Connect website and the internal bug system.  Updates are batched.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis Great, I'll remember that in my next feedback. Thank.

Answer (score -1):

It's a CTP right now, which isn't really supposed to be *stable*; on the contrary - it has experimental features. So it shouldn't really surprise you that it crashes. Gather as much data as possible and send it to Microsoft; hopefully they'll fix it.